# Comparing todays date to one listed in the database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am using mysql and php to pull all the users out of the mysql database that are equal to todays date. The problem I am having is whenever I run the following code I get an error. By the look of the error is seems to be something to do with the year, or maybe it doesn't like the dots in it, but im not sure ?.

```
<?php
$today = date("d.m.y");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ymeg_chronoforms_data_NewsletterSubscribe
 WHERE date=$today")or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['email']. " " . $row['date'];
 echo "<br />";
  }

  ?>
```

This is the error it is throwing :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.12' at line 2
```

Comment: enclose it in quotes and add backticks to date: ``date` = '$today'`

Comment: What type is your `date` column in the database?

Comment: try replacing WHERE date='$today'; at query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add quotes around your date string:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ymeg_chronoforms_data_NewsletterSubscribe
WHERE date='$today'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Need quotes around your `$today` variable.  Also need to backtick the `date` column name since it's reserved.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ymeg_chronoforms_data_NewsletterSubscribe
      WHERE `date`='$today'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $today should be added as a string into the SQL query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ymeg_chronoforms_data_NewsletterSubscribe WHERE `date` = '$today'");
```

`date` is a SQL reserved word so it has to be escaped with backticks...

But I recomment using MySQL native functions and constants like `NOW()`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `SYSDATE` etc...

```
SELECT * FROM ymeg_chronoforms_data_NewsletterSubscribe WHERE `date` = NOW()
SELECT * FROM ymeg_chronoforms_data_NewsletterSubscribe WHERE `date` < NOW() - INTERVAL '2' DAYS
SELECT * FROM ymeg_chronoforms_data_NewsletterSubscribe WHERE `date` > NOW() + INTERVAL '5' HOURS
```

etc...

Comment: Assuming that `date` column is actually the `date` type

Comment: :) I had the same thought, but based on the string format being used I couldn't tell. Probably need to add backticks for `date` to your second set of code

Answer (score 0):

if you are using timestamp as datatype in mysql then you need to convert the date into unix timestamp first.

```
$today = strtotime("now");
```

or if you are using datetime or date data type then correct format is

```
YY-MM-DD, so you need to create the date accordingly. 

$today = ('Y-m-d');
```

and also in your query you are missing single quote.

```
"SELECT * FROM ymeg_chronoforms_data_NewsletterSubscribe WHERE date = '$today'"
```

however you can compare the date without using PHP's date function, directly using MYSQL NOW().

```
SELECT * FROM ymeg_chronoforms_data_NewsletterSubscribe WHERE date = NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$today = date("d-m-Y");
```

OR

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
```

Also, check the format of date column is equal to the format of the return value of `date()`.

If you have used `DATETIME` data type you may need to use matching format.

Also, wrap date value with single quotes...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ymeg_chronoforms_data_NewsletterSubscribe
WHERE date = '" . $today . "'")
```